# Change the color of a part of a TextView in strings.xml

Tags: android, string, textview

In my android app with Kotlin, I created a layout in which there's a TextView that shows some text. For the text I have an item in strings.xml where I want to change the color of part of this Text, I tried the following code :

```
<string name="description">the product is <font fgcolor="green"> free </font></string>
```

But, The color didn't change.
I just want to change the color of "free" to green, can someone explain how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<font color="#008000">free</font>` instead. According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML), the correct attribute name is `color` and it only supports hex codes.

Answer (score 2):

[Ben P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8298909/ben-p)'s awesome answer should satisfy your use case. However, I want to present to you another way you can achieve this.

You can use [SpannableString](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString) to achieve the same effect. With SpannableString, you can set several behaviours (color, font-weight, font-size, click-behaviour, etc) to any part of your String.

For the string in your question, you can do something like this:

```
// the textview you want to set your coloured text to
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

// declare the string you want to span as a Spannable
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("the product is free");  

// set the colour span        
wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 15, 19, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

// set the text to your TextView
textView.setText(wordtoSpan);
```